# Solving a system of linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Based on my previous post, I have been stuck on this for a few hours now. I want to solve for $x$ and $y$ from the equation $$\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt}=a-(b+c+d)y-bx.$$

The original two equations are: $$\frac{dx}{dt}=a-bx-\frac{cxy}{x+y} \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{cxy}{x+y}-(b+c+d)y
$$

$a,b,c,d,x,y$ are all nonnegative.

What is the best strategy?

Comment: IF you have two variables, shouldn't you have 2 equations?

Comment: I combined two equations into one by canceling out a nonlinear term. Is two equations mandatory?

Comment: @Anonymous probably you should show us the problem in its primordial form.

Comment: @James S. Cook OK. Anything to get some help! See edit.

Comment: @Amzoti Hi Amzoti! Simply that they are all nonnegative.

Comment: @Amzoti Is it really? How do you know? Have you solved it?

Comment: @Anonymous sorry, I tried, it is not in my powers. I found http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+%3D+[y^2]%2F[x%2By-xy]   from setting $d=b=0$ and $a=c=1$ in solving the phase equation $dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$. Even this is not much help and I have perhaps violated your stipulation of "positive values" as zero is, well, not. In general, I think your problem is a beast.